# JSF2 - Create programmatically HtmloutputLink

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, myfaces

I want create a set of Output links similar to this

```
<li>
    <h:outputLink value="#" styleClass="home">Home</h:outputLink>
    <h:outputLink value="#" styleClass="home">Help</h:outputLink>
    <h:outputLink value="#" styleClass="home">About</h:outputLink>
</li>
```

But, the content is dynamically and i used Tomahawk library with

```
<t:htmlTag value="ul" binding="#{sessionBean.menu}"
                styleClass="nav navbar-nav">

            </t:htmlTag>
```

I the method binding i want create the set of links

```
public UIComponent getMenu() {
    if (menu != null) {
        menu.getChildren().clear();
        HtmlOutputLink htmlOutputLink = new HtmlOutputLink();
        htmlOutputLink.setValue("#");
        //htmlOutputLink.set   //how to set the body link
        menu.getChildren().add(htmlOutputLink);
```

But I do not know how to set the body of link, what is the best way to set a body link o HTMLOutputLink commonent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add:

```
HtmlOutputText yourOuput = new HtmlOutputText ();
yourOuput.setValue("home"):
htmlOutputLink.getChildren().add(yourOuput);
```